# Chrome sends a request multiple times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

I have a Rails 3 app and just noticed that when using Chrome (on Mac) to access the app, every page on the site is being requested twice. This is happening in development and production (Heroku).  Firefox and Safari only send the request once. The behavior is the same even when I remove all layouts and content for the action. It seems like there's a MIME type issue. Has anyone fixed this problem?

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    render :text => 'a', :layout => false
  end
```

This is the server log in development:

> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Dec 13 10:33:33 -0800 2010
>
> Processing by PagesController#home as **HTML**
>
> Rendered text template (0.0ms)
>
> Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)

---

> Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon Dec 13 10:33:33 -0800 2010
>
> Processing by PagesController#home as */*
>
> Rendered text template (0.0ms)
>
> Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 1.7ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms)

Comment: I've got a similar problem With Chrome 9.0.597.98 on XP: everytime I get a (PHP) page, it hits the log 3 times (on the same second).
Any other browser I tried works well with that page (Firefox 3.6.13/14 on Linux/Windows, Opera/Windows, IE8, even Chromium/9.0.597.94/Linux).

Comment: I realize this is a very old question but I'm actually getting the reverse problem. For me, Chrome behaves well but Safari and Firefox are pounding my server (heroku or local) with two requests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found what caused my problem, and maybe yours: I used Google Chrome's extensions named [Web Server Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/najdkmbedaehkepolllmpdfccdgooajh) and [Web Technology Notifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fnpgnmindcbkjbpblcklealdhnogmlko) which made their own request.

After deactivating them, I got only one request per page.

Comment: This appears to be the case for me also. Only the extension I was using was ezLinkPreview.

Comment: This is still apparently a problem in late 2018. I am getting 5 or 6 repeats for each request. One easy way to check if an extension is the culprit is to open your site in an incognito window, which disables extensions.

Answer (score 5):

The problem may be related to this issue: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1872177

> Chrome is trying some aggressive tactics in its developer builds (I think that is cool). What they're doing is speculatively opening sockets to servers, and also opening a second socket if their first attempt doesn't get a response quickly enough. It's pretty easy to see how a bug in this stuff, or even just the expected behavior, could trigger abuse filters. But, as I said, I think it is worth doing. All these web startups will make more money if the Web is faster.

If your Rails app isn't responding quickly enough, it's possible that Chrome is attempting alternate ways of getting content back for the user; there may not be much you can do about it. Your response times are very fast, but depending on the spin-up time of the connection, that might be a part of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread while researching a similar issue. 
I have an HTML `<OBJECT>` whose data is being populated by a call to a php script. I am getting two calls (GET) to the PHP script when running in Chrome  27.0.1453.81, but only one from IE (10.0) or FF (19.0.2). Looking at the HTTP traffic, the second GET is being generated after the first GET, but before the first GET responded, so I'm inclined to agree with the suggestion that Chrome is being impatient and sending the second GET when it believes the first one has failed (which it hasn't).
My php script will always take a couple of seconds to run and I can't work around that, and this second call is causing me some grief, so I'm interested in any strategy that might control it.

Comment: Have you found anything that can be done about this? These repeated queries are triggering my abuse filters. My clients who use other browsers are fine.

Answer (score 0):

No, but I haven't been bothered by it. TBH I had totally forgotten about this post.