# PHP dynamic image loaded twice in Chrome?

Tags: php, google-chrome, captcha

I have a PHP file which generate dynamic content of image(Captcha Image)

The image need to be loaded and reloaded at client.

Here is the main page(test.html):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function reload_image(){
    $('#img').attr('src','img.php?'+Math.random());
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<img id="img" /><a href="javascript:reload_image();">Reload</a>
</html>
```

and the PHP file(img.php):

```
<?php
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
readfile('php.png');
```

Each time I click on the link "Reload", there are TWO logs in the apache access log, but only one in Chrome network monitor, here is the log:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2011:15:38:59 +0800] "GET /img.php?0.8672932190820575 HTTP/1.1" 200 249
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2011:15:38:59 +0800] "GET /img.php?0.8672932190820575 HTTP/1.1" 200 249
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2011:15:39:13 +0800] "GET /img.php?0.4399074970278889 HTTP/1.1" 200 249
127.0.0.1 - - [20/Feb/2011:15:39:14 +0800] "GET /img.php?0.4399074970278889 HTTP/1.1" 200 249
```

These scripts works fine in Firefox, is it a Chrome bug? How can I fix it?

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**

---

It seems the issue of the wrong HTML structure, I'VE put the content outside the `<body>`, if I put into it, there will be no such error in Chrome.

I've also updated my program, removed DTD declaration, after that, such error disappear as well.

SO I guess that I should not use strict DTD, because sometimes it's difficult to figure out :(

Comment: I've actually noticed Chrome making multiple requests before too. I've never looked into it though...some Google searches later returns this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4432378/chrome-sends-a-request-multiple-times Are you using a developer build of Chrome?

Comment: Seems to be the HTML DOM issue

Comment: What about `<a href="#" onclick="javascript:reload_image();">`